# Magento 2:Edit Customer Address Section

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, adminform

> I want to edit customer address section. (To change the required
>   fields and field names). Where is the file location to make this
>   change? I have enabled admin path hints. But was not able to succeed.
>   My Magento version is 2.1.8.
>
> http://i.prntscr.com/K8hC3aNuRmqn6TEOQll8QQ.png
>
> Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That address field section is an attribute you can change that name in database. Navigate `eav_attribute` table in data base search search that name in `frontend_label` and you can change the name and `is_required` field is for validation if  me`1`ans that field is required